# How to divide long rows into multiple smaller rows for an entire (very large) data spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Google Doc with data in its current format followed by desired format: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XlxEVcP6QpWYyOeflLmp_mKflCBclim_UQSeMkHByh8/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to create a template to rearrange a data set that is exported in a horrible format.  I have posted a link to a Google Doc that has an example of the data in its current format followed by how I need it to be formatted. Currently, all data for a given person is in a single row, and the ID # is repeated before each record, as shown. Each record consists of 12 columns, and this is repeated 31 times across a row, totaling 372 cells per row. There are 838 rows (or 837 without the headers).  I need either a set of formulas or a macro that will separate a single row of data (the 372 cells) into 31 rows of 12 columns for an entire spreadsheet. I have been able to accomplish this only with a single row (using the `offset` function and then again using `index`), but I am struggling to find a way to make it apply to every row on a worksheet. Once that first row is done, the formula goes no further. Ideally, the rearranged data will appear on a **new** worksheet. I can't just manually separate the rows and filter them by ID #, because then I would have to redo that every time I rerun the report. Please let me know if I can give any further clarification!

Comment: I know its not what you want exactly, but you could try using notepad++ for this. If you export your data as csv you could easily do what you want using regular expressions. Other tools will work too. However, if you show us some code it would be easier to help you program a macro in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula based solution.  It assumes that you can create a new sheet to reform the data.  Based on your description, sounds like this is what you want anyways.  I have dummied down the example to have 4 categories and 3 repeats per row. Change the 4 and 3 below to match your 12 and 31.  (Harder to take a snapshot like that!)

**Picture of data and results.**

Data.  You can pretend that my column header "A" is your "ID".

[image: data]

Results.  It repeats the headers for simplicity.  You can delete those out at the end.

[image: results]

**Formula** in `A1` on `Sheet2` and copied over 4 columns and down as many rows as needed.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$L$7,INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1,MOD(ROW()-1,3)*4+COLUMN())
```

**How it works**

- `INDEX` is used to return a given cell from the array of the entire data
- `INDEX` needs a row and column to retrieve so I used integer division to determine the row.  We know that a given row in the results needs to be repeated for as many repeats of the headers as there are.  In this case 3.  The `ROW()` refers to the row in the results, and the `-1` is to ensure that it starts at `0` instead of `1`.
- The column for `INDEX` comes from the same idea.  For a given row, it needs to get a column that is the current column "pushed" over by the repeating row.  The `MOD` here ensures that the column numbers repeat in a small range even though the row is becoming a large number.

Finally, this formula really relies on the results starting in `A1` on a fresh sheet.  You can do it differently, but the formulas will become (even more of) a mess.