# How to use VBA to reshape data in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set looks like this:

```
ID   | Date1| Thing1| Date2| Thing2| Date3| Thing3| Date4| Thing4|
1    |  a   |  xx   | b    |   xx  | c    | xx    | d    |  xx   |
2    |  e   |  xx   | f    |   xx  | g    | xx    | h    |  xx   |
```

I would like to change that  to a long table like this:

```
ID   | Date| Thing|
 1   |  a  | xx   |
 1   |  b  | xx   |
 1   |  c  | xx   |
 1   |  d  | xx   |
 2   |  e  | xx   |
 2   |  f  | xx   |
 2   |  g  | xx   |
 2   |  h  | xx   |
```

I know how to do that in R but it is really confused for me in excel.

Can anyone help me set up some vba code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the macro recorder to get started. It will record what you do by hand and turn it into code which you can then review in the VBA editor. Simple copy & paste should do.

Comment: If the column `ID` were repeated as well, you could as take a formula approach using the [idea here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270031/how-to-divide-long-rows-into-multiple-smaller-rows-for-an-entire-very-large-da/30271533#30271533).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here one of the variant from my side

```
Sub test()
    Dim Key, Dic As Object, cl As Range, Data As Range, i&, n&
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    n = 1
    Set Data = Range("B2:B" & i & "," & "D2:D" & i & "," & "F2:F" & i & "," & "H2:H" & i)
    Dic.Add "|ID", "Date|Thing"
    For Each cl In Data
        If Cells(cl.Row, "A") <> "" Then
            Dic.Add n & "|" & Cells(cl.Row, "A"), cl.Text & "|" & cl.Offset(, 1).Text
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next cl
    n = 1
    For Each Key In Dic
        Cells(n, "K") = Split(Key, "|")(1)
        Cells(n, "L") = Split(Dic(Key), "|")(0)
        Cells(n, "M") = Split(Dic(Key), "|")(1)
        n = n + 1
    Next Key
End Sub
```

output

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try something like this

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 questions very similar to yours

[Get all combinations of the first column's value and other column's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426525/get-all-combinations-of-the-first-columns-value-and-other-columns-value)

[Extract categories from columns into duplicated rows with new category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722039/extract-categories-from-columns-into-duplicated-rows-with-new-category)

https://superuser.com/questions/683413/transform-horizontal-table-layout-to-vertical-table

I would adapt answer https://superuser.com/a/683439/245595 to your case, it is very easy. Some of the slight changes you need:

1. Extend `rng_all` as needed.
2. Instead of using `icol`, `ncols`, etc., and sweeping across columns for each ID, you waould have to use `icase`, `ncases`, etc., and sweep across cases:

   `ncases = ( WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_curr) - 1 ) / 2`

   `For icase = 1 To ncases`
3. Change slighlty code inside the loop.
4. Add code for copying the third column for each case.

If non-VBA is ok, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20800915/2707864) can be used.